# Getting source location from TypeDefinition with Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, pdb-files, mono.cecil

I would like to determine which source file defines a specific type using Mono.Cecil.

For methods, I can use the SequencePoint collection (for example, I could grab the first SequencePoint and fetch the Url of it's Document). I'm assuming this would always work as long as the PDBs are loaded since even empty methods should have at least one instruction (nop):

```
      if (methodDefinition.DebugInformation.HasSequencePoints) {
        var firstSequencePoint = methodDefinition.DebugInformation.SequencePoints[0];
        return firstSequencePoint.Document.Url;
      }
```

However, for types, I am not sure how this would work. Do the PDB files even contain the mapping between a type and a document? Obviously a type can be defined across multiple documents (in case of partial classes, for instance) which is fine - but is this information actually available? If yes, is it exposed in Mono.Cecil? Mono.Cecil.Cil.PortablePdbReader does read CustomDebugInformation for a module but I don't think this is it (I looked at the raw data and it doesn't contain anything of interest).

Comment: Note: one way would be to go over all methods in a type and collect corresponding documents (a type can be defined across multiple documents) but this would not always work (some types only have an empty constructor with no sequence points).

Comment: Note: I found a completely different approach. Since I have full access to source code that compiles, I was able to use Roslyn's SemanticModel to dump all types. The gist of it is iterating over compilation.SyntaxTrees and using semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(typeDeclarationSyntax)?.ToDisplayString() mapping to syntaxtTree.FilePath. Does not answer my question, but gives me a functional workaround.